# How to pass current data into predefined function with useCallback in react?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, react-typescript

I'm currently using nextjs and react to build an app and I'm trying to open a model using a function, passing data from the current state.

I'm successfully obtaining data from my supabase database when it is updated and I'm logging it in a useEffect when it is updated, I also store this in a ref for safe measure. When the function runs a previous value of rolesAndAllowedRef.current is logged meaning outdated parameters are being passed to the function. I'm aware that the issue is likely because I've defined the function already but I'm not sure how to fix it so that the current data in rolesAndAllowdRef.current is passed into the function, I've tried using useCallback however this has not fixed the issue. How can I fix this? Below is the code in my file.

```
"use client";

import { Edit, Trash } from "lucide-react";
import { useParams, useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import { ModalType, useModal } from "../../../hooks/use-modal-store";
import { ActionTooltip } from "../util/ActionTooltip";
import { iconMap, iconMapSidebar } from "./space/data";
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useRoleUpdateEffect } from "../modals/hooks/useRoleUpdateEffect";
import { createClientComponentClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs";

interface CollectiveSpaceProps {
  spaces: Space[];
  space: Space;
  collective: Collective;
  userRole: Role;
  roles: Role[];
}

export const CollectiveSpace = ({
  spaces,
  space,
  collective,
  userRole,
  roles,
}: CollectiveSpaceProps) => {
  const { onOpen } = useModal();
  const params = useParams();
  const router = useRouter();
  const supabase = createClientComponentClient();
  const onClick = () => {
    router.push(`/collective/${params?.unique}/${space.slug}`);
  };
  const [rolesAndAllowed, setRolesAndAllowed] = useState<RoleAndAllowed[]>(
    roles.map((role) => ({ ...role, allowed: space.allowed.includes(role.id) }))
  );

  const rolesAndAllowedRef = useRef(rolesAndAllowed);
  const onAction = useCallback(
    (e: React.MouseEvent, action: ModalType) => {
      console.log(rolesAndAllowedRef.current);
      e.stopPropagation();
      onOpen(action, {
        space,
        collective,
        spaces,
        rolesAndAllowed: rolesAndAllowedRef.current,
      });
    },
    [onOpen, space, collective, spaces, rolesAndAllowedRef]
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    rolesAndAllowedRef.current = rolesAndAllowed;

    console.log(rolesAndAllowedRef.current);
  }, [rolesAndAllowed, onOpen, space, collective, spaces]);
  useRoleUpdateEffect(
    supabase,
    collective,
    rolesAndAllowed,
    setRolesAndAllowed
  );
  /* so error is that I can't pass the updated roles into the edit space modal and then the create space modal meaning that the roles being eidted are outdated */
  return (
    <button
      onClick={onClick}
      className={cn(
        "group px-2 py-2 rounded-md flex items-center gap-x-2 w-full hover:bg-zinc-700/10 dark:hover:bg-zinc-700/50 transition mb-1",
        params?.spaceId === space.id && "bg-zinc-700/20 dark:bg-zinc-700"
      )}
    >
      {iconMapSidebar[space?.type as keyof typeof iconMap]}
      <p
        className={cn(
          "line-clamp-1 font-semibold text-sm text-zinc-500 group-hover:text-zinc-600 dark:text-zinc-400 dark:group-hover:text-zinc-300 transition",
          params?.spaceId === space.id &&
            "text-primary dark:text-zinc-200 dark:group-hover:text-white"
        )}
      >
        {<>{space.name}</>}
      </p>
      {space.name !== "general" && userRole.canCreate && (
        <div className="flex items-center ml-auto gap-x-2">
          <ActionTooltip label="Edit">
            <Edit
              onClick={(e) => onAction(e, "editSpace")}
              className="hidden w-4 h-4 transition group-hover:block text-zinc-500 hover:text-zinc-600 dark:text-zinc-400 dark:hover:text-zinc-300"
            />
          </ActionTooltip>
          <ActionTooltip label="Delete">
            <Trash
              onClick={(e) => onAction(e, "deleteSpace")}
              className="hidden w-4 h-4 transition group-hover:block text-zinc-500 hover:text-zinc-600 dark:text-zinc-400 dark:hover:text-zinc-300"
            />
          </ActionTooltip>
        </div>
      )}
    </button>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

-> In modify code :- 'rolesAndAllowedRef' using 'useRef' To hold the latest state value of 'rolesAndAllowed' and Created 'setRolesAndAllowed' function using 'useCallback' to update the 'rolesAndAllowedRef.current'

-> changing in onAction function to use the  'rolesAndAllowedRef.current' instead of the 'rolesAndAllowed' state directly and useEffect hook added in 'rolesAndAllowed.currect' when roles or space props change.

-> modify your code :-

```
import { useRef, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

export const CollectiveSpace = ({
  spaces,
  space,
  collective,
  userRole,
  roles,
}: CollectiveSpaceProps) => {
  const rolesAndAllowedRef = useRef<RoleAndAllowed[]>(roles.map((role) => ({ ...role, allowed: space.allowed.includes(role.id) })));

  const setRolesAndAllowed = useCallback((newState: RoleAndAllowed[]) => {
    rolesAndAllowedRef.current = newState;
  }, []);

  const onAction = useCallback(
    (e: React.MouseEvent, action: ModalType) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      onOpen(action, {
        space,
        collective,
        spaces,
        rolesAndAllowed: rolesAndAllowedRef.current,
      });
    },
    [onOpen, space, collective, spaces]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    rolesAndAllowedRef.current = roles.map((role) => ({ ...role, allowed: space.allowed.includes(role.id) }));
  }, [roles, space]);

  const onClick = () => {
    router.push(`/collective/${params?.unique}/${space.slug}`);
  };

  return (
    <button
      onClick={onClick}
      className={cn(
        "group px-2 py-2 rounded-md flex items-center gap-x-2 w-full hover:bg-zinc-700/10 dark:hover:bg-zinc-700/50 transition mb-1",
        params?.spaceId === space.id && "bg-zinc-700/20 dark:bg-zinc-700"
      )}
    >
      {/* Your button content here */}
    </button>
  );
};
```